# Fabric JS: how to set controlls to be always visible?

Tags: fabricjs

How can I set controls to be always visible even when object is not active and is a part of a group?

Comment: part of a group that is not active, or part of the active selection made with mouse?

Comment: Both. I'd like to see all controls of all objects that are on canvas.